# Access property within javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a property within an object and return it.

Note the name of the object can change, so accessing it using `title_can_change.property` will not work.

Take the following object:

```
{
 "title_can_change":{
   property: 1
 }
}
```

How do I return the value of 'property'?

MORE INFO:

This object is being returned from a search which contains an array of results from several API's.  This object is returned to detail the API the result has come from (the search goes through several API's).

So this would be more like:

```
apiData:{
 "apiName":{
   price: 500
 }
}
```

**"apiName" is not fixed and changes to say the name of the API.  So it cannot be referenced by "apiName' in any of the code.**

Comment: Is this the only property under "title_can_change" with that particular name?

Comment: No, other properties can exist, but the name 'property' is fixed.

Comment: can you provide more details like how are you changing the title, some more context around the actual use scenario but one thing i can think of is to assign a reference to the object and use that reference

Comment: it feels like a really simple thing to achieve if you put more context around this

Comment: Agreed. How are you referencing the actual object? Is it part of an array? If so, you should be able to accomplish what you're after using map or reduce, but more context is needed to properly help you.

Comment: More information added - thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of any number of map accessor questions.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Use `for...in` to iterate over the keys of the object and check if your inner object contains your property

```
var o = {
    "title_can_change":{
        property: 1
    }
};

for (var k in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(k) && o[k].property) {
        return o[k].property;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this `object` is global, then you can use `window['title_can_change']['property']`. If it's just another property of another object (called another_one) you can access it with `another_one['title_can_change']['property']`.

Furthermore: You can have a variable (let's call it `title_name`) to ease the call:

```
....
var title_name = "title_can_change";
var myObj = window[title_name]['property'];
title_name = "title_has_changed";
var anotherObj = window[title_name]['property'];
.....
```

OR

```
....
var title_name = "title_can_change";
var myObj = another_one[title_name]['property'];
title_name = "title_has_changed";
var anotherObj = another_one[title_name]['property'];
.....
```

Comment: But if "title_can_change" changes to "title_has_changed", this won't work, will it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to return the value of the property of whatever object you pass to it:

```js
var getProperty = function(obj) {
    return obj.property;
};
```

Comment: +1 as this is the only other answer that does not require a nested object and used the language itself to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object and you want to access it's first key's value you can go with something like this (dirty example):

```
var myObj = {
 "title_can_change"{
   property: 1
 }
}

myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[0]];
```

I home this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I know what you are wanting and here is a low-level solution that may prove valuable and show you some neat things about the language.

https://jsfiddle.net/s10pg3sh/1/

```
function CLASS(property) {
  // Set the property on the class
  this.property = property || null;
}

// Add a getter for that property to the prototype
CLASS.prototype.getProperty = function() {
  return this['property'];
}

var obj = new CLASS(9);
alert(obj.getProperty());
```

What you are doing in the above is creating a "class" for your new variable. When you create your object with the `new` keyword as show you still get your normal JS object (everything is an object anyways), but you get the convenience of the `getProperty` method. This being on the prototype insures that any `new CLASS` variables you create will have that method. You can change the variable names and you will always have access to that property by having access to the instance (variable). This is a very common OO paradigm and is the strength of a prototypical language so while it may be over the top for your needs I figured I would add it as an answer here...

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a guess here since the question is still somewhat unclear. I am assuming that you want to iterate over an objects properties whose names are unknown.

This might be a solution.

```
for (var property in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    // check objects properties for existence
    // do whatever you want to do
  }
}
```